# как сделать ожидание ответа на вопрос, прежде чем выведется следующий?

Tags: javascript

как реализовать паузу во время ожидания ответа на вопрос выведенный из массива questions.
Вовремя вывода вопроса через prompt() скрипт работает как надо. Но если вывод вопроса происходит не через prompt(), тогда выводится только последний вопрос из массива questions.

```
  var yesScore = 0, noScore = 0;

  var questions = [
   ['Сколько лун у планеты Земля ?', 1],
   ['Сколько лун у планеты Сатурн ?', 31],
   ['Сколько лун у планеты Венера ?', 0],
   ['Сколько 2 + 2 ?', 4]
 ];

 var scoreCounter = function() {
  var score = 0;

  return function() {
    return ++score;
 }
}

var scoreYes = scoreCounter();
var scoreNo = scoreCounter();

var askQuestions = function(question) {
  var inputForm = prompt(question[0]);

  if (inputForm == question[1]) {
    yesScore = scoreYes();
  } else {
    alert(question[1]);
    noScore = scoreNo();
  }
}

var i = 0;

while (i < questions.length) {
  askQuestions(questions[i]);
  i++;
}

console.log(yesScore, noScore);
```

нерабочий вариант кода

```
<div class="content">
    <h1 class="title"></h1>

    <form action="" method="post">
      <input type="text" value="" placeholder="напишите ответ числом">
      <input type="submit" value="ок">
    </form>

    <div>
      <p class="yes"></p>
      <p class="no"></p>
    </div>
   </div>

var content = document.querySelector('.content');
   var title = content.querySelector('.title');
   var inputForm = content.querySelector('input[type="text"]');
   var btnFormQuestion = content.querySelector('input[type="submit"]');

   var yesScore = 0, noScore = 0;

   var questions = [
     ['Сколько лун у планеты Земля ?', 1],
     ['Сколько лун у планеты Сатурн ?', 31],
     ['Сколько лун у планеты Венера ?', 0],
     ['Сколько 2 + 2 ?', 4]
   ];

   var scoreCounter = function() {
     var score = 0;

    return function() {
      return ++score;
    }
   }

  var scoreYes = scoreCounter();
  var scoreNo = scoreCounter();

  var askQuestions = function(question) {
    title.textContent = question[0];

    if (inputForm.value == question[1]) {
      yesScore = scoreYes();
    } else {
      title.textContent = 'правильный ответ ' + question[1];
      noScore = scoreNo();
    }
   }

var i = 0;

while (i < questions.length) {
  askQuestions(questions[i]);
  i++;
}

content.querySelector('.yes').textContent = 'верные ответы: ' + yesScore;
content.querySelector('.no').textContent = 'неверные ответы: ' + noScore;
```

Comment: Вам стоит показать именно тот вариант, который не работаете. Если вы спрашиваете не через `prompt()`, тогда как? `prompt()` блокирует исполнение скриптов и вообще функциональность страницы, это самый простой способ организовать ожидание, другие будут зависеть от вашей альтернативы.

Comment: в форме в инпут вводится числом ответ на вопроc,  после нажатия на кнопку происходит проверка введенного в инпут значения. После проверки в зависимости от того верный или нет был ответ счетчики срабатывают.

<form action="" method="post"><input type="text" value="" placeholder="напишите ответ числом"><input type="submit" value="ок"></form>

Comment: Лучше добавить минимальный код с HTML, воспроизводящий проблему, чтобы желающим было легче ответить.

Comment: Возможный алгоритм: при загрузке страницы задаётся первый вопрос. Создайте кнопку, при нажатии на которую проверяется ответ и задаётся следующий вопрос. Вопросы можно извлекать из массива. Когда массив опустеет, кнопка удаляется или делается неактивной и выводится результат.